# using ref in typescript nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I learning typescript in react but got an warning

```js
import {useref} from 'react'

export default function test(){
   cons tmp = useRef()
   const data = tmp.current?.value
   return (
      <div>
        <input type ="text" ref={tmp}/>
      </div>

) }
```

but I got warning like this

```js
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)
```

can someone help me to fix it ?

and one more question, what Type Annotation of props.example() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to provide a type to `useRef` so it know what to expect. You also need to initialize it as `null`.

```
const tmp = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
```

Then everything works as you expect.

[Working example on Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&ssl=4&ssc=22&pln=4&pc=38#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzksgGZwC+cpUEIcA5FKhgwFBtIAekscAJklIp8AG3il8AOwzAIUuDCSEYACgCUONnDhp5KxeDgBeAsTIAeABIAVALIAZAJJSw+GAFFRSEEikwAPlUpMVF1bV19eH4UGBQTQzAAOjR8KGZ-AH4kgDcUUXwkCOYYNIVVCJ0LfmAcgMqdOAtgV3dFAE8wJBMAIiUuGB64ZlJjHBhwCgB6esamqZq6iPCKIA)

Comment: thanks, I have 1 more question, if I have a props example props.example(), what type annotation ?

Comment: Typically I defined react props like so: https://tsplay.dev/m3Akbw but if you need more help than that, please make a new question where you can explain your situation in full and get the proper help that you need.